# Write a tweet using "twitterOAuth" return an error

Tags: php, debugging, twitter, bots, twitter-oauth

I have this problem and are a lot of days that i'm tring to solve it.

I write a tweet using `twitterOAuth`

```
// OAuth To Twitter
require_once 'files-notifiche-twitter/twitteroauth.php';

// Do NOT Share (sono i token)
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "xxx");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "xxx");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "xxx");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "xxx");

// Post To Twitter
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'tweet'));


if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() != 200) {    //se non è riuscito a scrivere il tweet riprova
    print_r('<br>Error try again<br>');     
} 
else{
    print_r('<br>Notifica twitter funziona<br>');
}

print_r('OK');
```

This code works to write the tweet but then, in the last part, is how ther's an error...infact the `print_r` inside **if statement** is didn't write.
The same for last `print_r('OK')`

Something break my code and i don't understand what....

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you running this code in command line `php your-php-file.php` ?

Comment: @JaredChu no...every 2 minute a cronjob run my code. Where do you think can be the error ?

Comment: I want to reproduce the error so I must know the way you're doing

Comment: Yes you are right... maybe i'm using a old version of twitterOAuth or OAuth.php ? (in twitterOAuth there's a require_once('OAuth.php') maybe is old)

Comment: i read on github, in profile of Abraham Williams that created this method, but i don't understand where are files and i don't know how use Github. I'm not english and for me is difficult